# OpenCV: OutputArray usage without copy

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I need to extend kernel from one channel to more channels. For example from

```
0  1 0
1 -4 1
0  1 0
```

to

```
0 0 0  1  1  1 0 0 0
1 1 1 -4 -4 -4 1 1 1
0 0 0  1  1  1 0 0 0
```

following standard three channels `cv::Mat`.

I have following code:

```
void createKernel(InputArray _A, InputArray _B, OutputArray _kernel, const int chn)
{
    Mat A = _A.getMat();
    Mat B = _B.getMat();
    Mat kernel;
    Mat kernelOneChannel = A * B;
    std::vector<Mat> channels;

    for (int i = 0; i < chn; i++)
    {
        channels.push_back(kernelOneChannel);
    }

    merge(channels, kernel);    
    kernel.copyTo(_kernel);
}
```

One channel kernel is copied to `std:vector` as many times based on the `chn`. After that is one multi channel `cv::Mat` created.

My question is about the last line `kernel.copyTo(_kernel)`. In many examples what I have seen, this is the way how to deal with `Outputarray`. Is this `copyTo` really needed? It seems to me like waste of memory and time to copy already computed `kernel` to the `_kernel`. Is there any solution without this data copy from one structure to another?

My question is strictly related to OpenCV and mentioned structures.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your specific case you can pass `_kernel` variable directly to `merge` call to avoid unnessesary copy:

```
merge(channels, _kernel)
```

In general case the `OutputArray` object is supposed to be used in the following way:

```
_outArr.create(size, type);
Mat outMat = _outArr.getMat();
```

Now the `outMat` variable can be filled without extra copies.